# Docker Hub Build Failure - Failed to build rapidfuzz

Tags: python, docker, dockerhub

I have a relatively simple python service built successfully as a Docker image locally on windows when the same code is built in Docker Hub I get the following error:

Failed to build rapidfuzz
ERROR: Could not build wheels for rapidfuzz, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

The build is failing at this point in the
`RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`

which contains the following dependencies
flask
openbb
seqlog

It is failing at openbb I assume but that is not the question. My question is this, why would it succeed on my machine but not in Docker Hub and why cannot it build rapidfuzz?